# Latex: Insert vertical space after includegraphics

Tags: latex, space

I'm using the `scrartcl` documentclass and try to insert some vertical space after including an image.

```
Lorem ipsum...\\\\
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image.png}

% Add vertical space here
Lorem ipsum...
```

Before the image I can just add like `\\\\` to add some space (which I don't like as well...), but I can't add these after the image because there is no line to end.

Is there an option to add a margin before and after the image?

I know that I could use figures, but I like the simple way of just adding one simple line of `\inludegraphics{blah}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should try using `\vspace`. `\\` just adds newlines while `\vspace` adds vertical skips. Alternatively you could use `\smallskip`, `\medskip`, or `\bigskip`.